# paypal subscription first IPN txn_type when doing new registeration for subscription

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, paypal-ipn

I am now testing some IPN for our subscription system.
from this document https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside
the documentation is complete but i need some more confirmation on these..

1. when is the first time paypal will send an IPN when user doing new registration for a subscription?
2. do "amount1" and "amount3" also sent after the first payment?
3. from these combination of parameters in the documentation above. how i can tell that the notification is for a trial payment? or a regular payment or for 1st payment?

I cant find a tool for doing subscription IPN test.. even in the paypal sandbox/developer site. i wonder if anybody can suggest me how to easily test these things.

Comment: For 1 and 2 and possibly 3, if you're testing your IPN system, shouldn't you be able to find that out? Change the subscription dates to recur more frequently (such as daily) to test sooner rather than later.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I believe you suggest me doing it on a live environment not the sandbox? i was thinking the same but daily seems not fast enough frequency . probably like every minute? :D but they dont have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create business a/c and personal a/c on sandbox( https://developer.paypal.com/ ).

Do ipn Setting in business a/c

Sandbox can send you the transaction data (also called Instant Payment Notification) to a specific url. With Instant Payment Notification, PayPal sends payment notification messages with encrypted code to the specified URL for each payment you receive. Follow the instructions below to setup Instant Payment Notification.

1. Go to the sandbox( https://developer.paypal.com/ ) website and log in to your account(business account).
2. Click "Profile" at the top of the page.
3. Click "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" in the Selling Preferences column.
4. Click "Edit IPN Settings."
5. Enter the notification URL and select "Receive IPN messages."
6. Click "Save."

You can send customized emails from the Instant Payment Notification data. Please see http://paypaltech.com/SG2 for sample scripts.

we can customize sample script code according our need.

Comment: is the IPN for subscription the same as the normal payment?

Comment: Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service that sends a notification when a transaction is affected on ur business A/c.

Comment: Hi Vikas, I just looked at your website and it looks reaaly good!

Comment: How do yuo know that the instant payment notification sent to your url refers to a cancellation of recurring payment?

Comment: @JohnMerlino , i have already told  PayPal sends payment notification messages with encrypted code to the specified URL for each payment you receive, for that use that one code // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'  
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';  
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  
$req .= "&$key=$value";  
} and update information in database related to particular user

Comment: @JohnMerlino we have to make code already return url of ipn and save information according your need